# What is smooth structure on the exterior algebra of cotangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let  $(T^*M, \pi, M)$ be cotangent bundle, where

$$ T^*M := \bigsqcup_{m\in M} T^*_m M$$
is a set equipped with corresponding topology $O_{T^*M}$ and smooth structure $A_{T^*M}$.

Then at each point $m\in M$ we can define $k$-exterior power of the cotangent space $\Lambda^k(T^*_mM)$.

Then we can define:
$$ \Lambda^k(T^*M) := \bigsqcup_{m\in M} \Lambda^k(T^*_mM) $$
**Question: How do I equip this set with a topology and smooth structure?**

I want to be able to construct bundle $(\Lambda^k(T^*M), \pi', M)$ and then define module of smooth $k$-forms as a module of smooth sections $\Gamma(M, \Lambda^k(T^*M))$, but to do so I need first to transform the set above into a smooth manifold and I don't know how to do it properly. Any tips?

**Edit 1:**
We can define initial topology on $\Lambda^k(T^*M)$ with respect to projection map $\pi'$:
$$ \pi': \Lambda^k(T^*M) \to M  \\
   (m, \alpha) \mapsto m $$
 as such, we can pick

$$ B := \{ \text{preim}_{\pi'}(U) \in 2^{\Lambda^k(T^*M)}  | \forall U \in O_M\}$$

to be a subbasis. Then we can define topology $O_{\Lambda^k(T^*M)}$ as generated by this subbasis, i.e. set of all unions of finite intersections of elements of $B$.

That is $(\Lambda^k(T^*M), O_{\Lambda^k(T^*M)})$ - topological space, such that $\pi'$ is continious.

Now the only thing left is to find smooth atlas $A_{\Lambda^k(T^*M)}$ with respect to which $\pi'$ will become smooth map.

Comment: Try to use the functoriality of the exterior power to turn the gluing data (triviality over open sets, compatible isomorphisms, etc.) Of the cotangent bundle into the gluing data for the exterior power bundle.

Comment: @Lorenzo I guess to start even talking about gluing for the exterior power one need to establish topology on it first to turn it into topological space. I was thinking about trivial topology (maybe discrete), but don't know if it'll do the job.

Comment: Finite dimensional spaces have a natural topology, which isn't trivial.

Comment: @Lorenzo Okay, I figured out that I can just pick an initial topology so that projection will become continious with respect to it. I think it is only left to find for each open set a suitable homeomorphism to some $\mathbb{R}^m$ to construct an atlas and then prove that it is smooth.